# Compare two collections with linq and populate variable

Tags: c#, linq

I have two identical collections, 1 which gets passed to the view and the other which gets stored in the session before I display the view.

We are using hidden fields on the view, inside these hidden fields is a SenderId.  When the user submits the page I want to compare the submitted SenderId's with the SenderId's in the Session collection and populate a variable with the Id's that don't match (which would mean the user has tampered with the hidden fields)

This is what I currently have:

```
 var storedValues = (List<MailBox>)Session["Mail"];
 var noMatch = (from x in model where storedValues.Any(s => s.SenderId != x.SenderId) select x.SenderId).ToList();
```

But no matter what I do it always selects all of them even though I change the SenderId's on the view and when debugging I can see the SenderId which I have tampered with, I can't for the life of me get the variable noMatch to populate with the incorrect SenderId I have tampered with.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update Model Declaration:

```
public class MailBox
{
    public Int64 SenderId { get; set; }

    public Int64 RecipientId { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public int TotalMessages { get; set; }

    public string PhotoId { get; set; }

    public bool NewMessages { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastLoggedIn { get; set; }

    public DateTime LatestEmailDate { get; set; }

    public bool LoggedIn { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public bool Delete { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'd try another syntax like: storedValues.Where(x => x.SenderId != s.SenderId)

Comment: @SebastianL I've tried that, but I get the error: argument is not assignable to parameter type bool

Comment: Please show how `model` is defined.

Comment: @Kapol added the model

Answer (score 0):

If the collections are the same size you can use .Zip()

```
collection1.Zip(colection2, (col1_item, col2_item) =>
{
   if(col1_item.SomeProperty == col2_item.SomeProperty)
   {
        //
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to now resolve this issue, by doing the following:

```
 var noMatch = model.Where(item => item.Delete && storedValues.Any(x => x.SenderId == item.SenderId)).Select(item => item.SenderId).ToList();
```